# Visual Studio 2012 C++ arrays initialization using { }

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, initialization

i've just started programming in visual studio 2012 Express and from the beginning I'm having problems with arrays.

The environment says that this code is invalid:

```
int a[10] = {5,1,8,9,7, 2,3,11, 20,15};
```

First of all i had to declare that this array has fixed size using `fixed` keyword, but after that the program still has been wanting to put `;` after `a[10]`. Filling up this array one number by one would be waste of time. Is it possible to work around it? I can't find any solution in google so I decided to post my problem here.

Comment: Post the error? Also: which "fixed" keyword are you talking about?

Comment: Compiles for me (VS2012 Ultimate, Update 4).

Comment: There is no keyword `fixed` in C++.

Comment: No error found,Compiled successfully.

Comment: It should not give any error. It is strange the compiler wants `;` after the declaration. Can you post a bit more of code, for example your `main ` function? Anyway, don't use `fixed`.

Comment: BTW, specifying array size is redundant when brace-initializing: it will be deduced anyway from number of initializers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- There's no `fixed` keyword in C++, perhaps in C#
- The code you posted is perfectly valid in VS2012 Ultimate (and probably also Express)

From the above I might conclude you mismatched project and are trying to compile a C++ code in a C# environment.

Another reason that makes me think the above is the following error you get in a **C# project** if you try to compile the snippet above:

> error CS0650: Bad array declarator: To declare a managed array the
>   rank specifier precedes the variable's identifier. To declare a fixed
>   size buffer field, use the fixed keyword before the field type.

which refers exactly to the `fixed` keyword you were trying to use.

---

Short story: you're trying to compile a C++ code in a C# project. Paste that code in a C++ project, not a C# one. Those are two different languages.

Comment: Yup. That's the problem. I didn't noticed that by usings I don't know why.

Answer (score -1):

May be its  too late to but you can use STL array for fix size arrays as

```
#include <array>
std::array<int, 5> ary { 1,2,3,4,5 }
```

This will be a fixed size array

As mentioned by Marco A. there is no "fixed" keyword in C++